# Android App in Kotlin not inflating Fragment Layout properly

Tags: android, kotlin

I have a Problem.

I wrote a Java Android App and converted to Kotlin. It worked in Java jsut fine but now when I run the app it gives me a RuntimeError. The Fragment cant be inflated:

**Errors**

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.jaielsoft.www.emergencyapp, PID: 10753
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.jaielsoft.www.emergencyapp/de.htw_berlin.f4.ai.aa.activities.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class fragment
    ...
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class fragment
    ....
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter specified as non-null is null: method kotlin.jvm.internal.Intrinsics.checkParameterIsNotNull, parameter savedInstanceState    
    ....
```

Here are the involved classes and layout files:

**MainActivity.kt:**

```
package de.htw_berlin.f4.ai.aa.activities

...

class MainActivity : FragmentActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        if (savedInstanceState == null)
            this.setContentView(R.layout.mainlayout)
    }
}
```

**mainlayout.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<fragment
    android:name="de.htw_berlin.f4.ai.aa.fragments.MainFragment"
    android:id="@+id/main_menu_fragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**MainFragment.kt**

```
package de.htw_berlin.f4.ai.aa.fragments

...

class MainFragment : Fragment() {
        override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle): View? {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.mainfragmentlayout, container, false)
    }

}
```

**mainfragmentlayout.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/blue"
        android:contentDescription="@null" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/sosButton"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/contactsButton"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/contactsButton"
        android:onClick="callForHelp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="98dp"
        android:background="@null"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/emergencybutton"
        android:contentDescription="@null"/>

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/contactsButton"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="57dp"
        android:background="@null"
        android:onClick="startContactActivity"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/contactsbutton"
        android:contentDescription="@null" />

<ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/mapButton"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="23dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:onClick="startMapActivity"
        android:background="@null"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/mapbutton"
        android:contentDescription="@null"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Where is the Problem? Can you please help me?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this line of your `MainFragment`

```
 override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle): View? {
```

to

```
 override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
```

Note that I made `savedInstanceState` nullable with `Bundle?` instead of `Bundle`. 
This is a bit of a problem in general when overriding methods from Java classes in Kotlin, sometimes you don't know exactly if a parameter can be null or not. 
In this case, `onCreateView` can (and will) be called with `savedInstanceState` being null, so you hav to make it nullable.